# Magento 2 convert current date time to gmtdate

Tags: magento2.4.0, datetime

How to convert current timezone date and time to gmtdate and time ?

Here I am adding some hours for todays date and wants to convert in gmtdate to filter order colleciton

```
//Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\TimezoneInterface

echo $toDay = $this->timezone->date()->format('Y-m-d H:i');

  $fromTime = strtotime($toDay);
  $toTime = $fromTime + 3600;
```

This below code gives current timezone time by adding one hour but I want to convert in gmt date and time

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i', $toTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime` class has a `gmtDate` function which can be used in your code since the `$this->timezone->date()` function will return a `DateTime` object:

```
echo $this->timezone->date()->gmtDate('Y-m-d h:i');
```